# Django loggers don't work when DEBUG=False

Tags: django, django-logging

I'm using Django==2.2.11 and djangorestframework==3.11.0.
When I run `./manage.py runserver` and make an http request to the endpoint that has some database queries I got all the logging information. This is only when `DEBUG = True`. If I set `DEBUG=False` I won't get any logging to console at all:

**settings.py**:

```
DEBUG = False

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'filters': [],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False
        },
    }
}
```